# C++ loops: how to get program to repeat "error" message more than once anytime user enters invalid input

Tags: c++, loops, debugging, if-statement, continue

I'm ALMOST done with this assignment, but still having trouble getting the code to display the error messages continuously until the correct input is entered.

For example, if the user enters "4" for operation (which should be between 1-3), it correctly displays: "Your operation choice isn't valid!  Please try again, using 1, 2, or 3." However, if the user enters another invalid number for the operation (such as 5), it doesn't repeat the error message, but just continues forward.

Anyone able to help me figure out how to get each error message to repeat until valid numbers or characters are entered for each prompt?

***Note: I am very new to coding, and still figuring out stackoverflow...I think I have followed all the MCVE suggestions/format. THANK YOU!!***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int operation, num3, guess, num1, num2, temp;
    char play;
    srand(time(0));

    do
    {
      num1 = rand() % 10;
      num2 = rand() % 10;

      if (num1 < num2)
      {
          temp = num1;
          num1 = num2;
          num2 = temp;
      }
        do
        {
            cout << "Choose an operation." << endl;
            cout << "Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply: " << 
endl;
            cout << "" << endl;
            cin >> operation;
            cout << "" << endl;

            if (operation > 3 || operation < 1)
            {
                cout << "Your operation choice isn't valid!  Please try 
again, using 1, 2, or 3." << endl;
                cout << "" << endl;
                cout << "Choose an operation." << endl;
                cout << "Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply: " 
<< endl;
                cout << "" << endl;
                cin >> operation;
                cout << "" << endl;
            }
        }
        while (operation > 3 || operation < 1);

        switch(operation)
        {
            case 1:
            cout << "You chose addition." << endl;
            num3 = num1 + num2;
            cout << "" << endl;
            cout << "What is " <<  num1 << " + " << num2 << " ?: " << endl;
            cout << "" << endl;
            cin >> guess;
            cout << "" << endl;

                if (guess != num3)
                    {
                    cout << "That is incorrect. Please try again." << endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    cout << "What is " <<  num1 << " + " << num2 << " ?: " 
<< endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    cin >> guess;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    }

                else if (guess == num3)
                    {
                    cout << "That is correct!" << endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    }
            break;

            case 2:
                cout << "You chose subtraction." << endl;
                num3 = num1 - num2;
                cout << "What is " <<  num1 << " - " << num2 << " ?: " << 
endl;
                cout << "" << endl;
                cin >> guess;
                cout << "" << endl;

                    if (guess != num3)
                        {
                        cout << "That is incorrect. Please try again." << 
endl;
                        cout << "" << endl;
                        cout << "What is " <<  num1 << " - " << num2 << " ?: 
" << endl;
                        cout << "" << endl;
                        cin >> guess;
                        }

                    else if (guess == num3)
                        {
                        cout << "That is correct!" << endl;
                        cout << "" << endl;
                        }
                break;

            case 3:
                cout << "You chose multiplication." << endl;
                num3 = num1 * num2;
                cout << "What is " <<  num1 << " * " << num2 << " ?: " << 
endl;
                cout << "" << endl;
                cin >> guess;
                cout << "" << endl;

                    if (guess != num3)
                        {
                        cout << "That is incorrect. Please try again." << 
endl;
                        cout << "" << endl;
                        cout << "What is " <<  num1 << " * " << num2 << " ?: 
" << endl;
                        cout << "" << endl;
                        cin >> guess;
                        }

                    else if (guess == num3)
                        {
                        cout << "That is correct!" << endl;
                        cout << "" << endl;
                        }
            break;
        }

        do
        {
             cout << "Would you like to play again? Press Y for yes or Q for 
quit" << endl;
             cout << "" << endl;
             cin >> play;

           if (play != 'Y' && play != 'Q')

            {
                cout << "That is not a valid choice. Please choose Y for yes 
or Q to quit. " << endl;
                cout << "" << endl;
            }

        }

        while(play !='Y' && play !='Q');

        if (play == 'Y')
        {
        cout << "Thank you for playing! Let's play again!" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        }

        else
        {
        cout << "Thank you for playing! See you next time!" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        }

     }
     while(play=='Y');
return 0;
}
/*Sample Run:
Choose an operation.
Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply:

3

You chose multiplication.
What is 4 * 1 ?:

4

That is correct!

Would you like to play again? Press Y for yes or Q for quit

Y
Thank you for playing! Let's play again!

Choose an operation.
Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply:

1

You chose addition.

What is 6 + 1 ?:

7

That is correct!

Would you like to play again? Press Y for yes or Q for quit

Y
Thank you for playing! Let's play again!

Choose an operation.
Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply:

2

You chose subtraction.
What is 5 - 0 ?:

5

That is correct!

Would you like to play again? Press Y for yes or Q for quit

Y
Thank you for playing! Let's play again!

Choose an operation.
Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply:

1

You chose addition.

What is 7 + 1 ?:

9

That is incorrect. Please try again.

What is 7 + 1 ?:

10

Would you like to play again? Press Y for yes or Q for quit

Y
Thank you for playing! Let's play again!

Choose an operation.
Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply:

2

You chose subtraction.
What is 7 - 3 ?:

5

That is incorrect. Please try again.

What is 7 - 3 ?:

6
Would you like to play again? Press Y for yes or Q for quit

Q
Thank you for playing! See you next time!


Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 43.057 s
Press any key to continue.
*/
```

Comment: *".I think I have followed all the MCVE suggestions/format."* **M** stands for **M**inimal, so your switch can be removed and just skip your inner `do while`.

Comment: Thanks for reading the [help] (I suppose you did? You already know about [mcve]), but you forgot to follow [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950). If you want you can  post that as a comment (although if the question is already good, theorically it should not be downvoted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### P29: Practice Arithmetic Skills (if/else , loop)

#### Description:

*"Write a program to let a child practice arithmetic skills.*

The program should first ask for what kind of practice is wanted: +, -, * , and let the user repeat the practice as many times as desired, until "Q" is entered.

Two random numbers will be generated from (0 - 9).

If the child answers the equation correctly, a message should appear , and they can then go to the next problem(two different numbers generated).

If the child answers incorrectly, a message should appear & the problem should be repeated (same numbers used)."

**Finally fixed!**:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
   {
    int operation, num3, guess, num1, num2, temp;
    char play;
    srand(time(0));

    do
    {
      num1 = rand() % 10;
      num2 = rand() % 10;

      if (num1 < num2)
      {
          temp = num1;
          num1 = num2;
          num2 = temp;
      }

        do
        {
            cout << "Choose an operation." << endl;
            cout << "Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply: " << endl;
            cout << "" << endl;
            cin >> operation;

            if (operation > 3 || operation < 1)
            {
                cout << "Your operation choice isn't valid!  Please try again, using 1, 2, or 3." << endl;
            }
        }while (operation > 3 || operation < 1);

        switch(operation)
        {
            case 1:
            cout << "You chose addition." << endl;
            num3 = num1 + num2;
            cout << "" << endl;

            do
            {
                cout << "What is " <<  num1 << " + " << num2 << " ?: " << endl;
                cout << "" << endl;
                cin >> guess;
                cout << "" << endl;

                if (guess != num3)
                    {
                    cout << "That is incorrect. Please try again." << endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    }
            } while (guess != num3);

                if (guess == num3)
                    {
                    cout << "That is correct!" << endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    }
            break;

            case 2:
            cout << "You chose subtraction." << endl;
            num3 = num1 - num2;
            cout << "" << endl;

            do
            {
                cout << "What is " <<  num1 << " - " << num2 << " ?: " << endl;
                cout << "" << endl;
                cin >> guess;
                cout << "" << endl;

                if (guess != num3)
                    {
                    cout << "That is incorrect. Please try again." << endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    }
            } while (guess != num3);

                if (guess == num3)
                    {
                    cout << "That is correct!" << endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    }
            break;

            case 3:
            cout << "You chose multiplication." << endl;
            num3 = num1 * num2;
            cout << "" << endl;

            do
            {
                cout << "What is " <<  num1 << " * " << num2 << " ?: " << endl;
                cout << "" << endl;
                cin >> guess;
                cout << "" << endl;

                if (guess != num3)
                    {
                    cout << "That is incorrect. Please try again." << endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    }
            } while (guess != num3);

                if (guess == num3)
                    {
                    cout << "That is correct!" << endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    }
            break;
        }

        do
        {
             cout << "Would you like to play again? Press Y for yes or Q for quit" << endl;
             cout << "" << endl;
             cin >> play;

           if (play != 'Y' && play != 'Q')

            {
                cout << "That is not a valid choice. Please choose Y for yes or Q to quit. " << endl;
                cout << "" << endl;
            }

        }

        while(play !='Y' && play !='Q');

        if (play == 'Y')
        {
        cout << "Thank you for playing! Let's play again!" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        }

        else
        {
        cout << "Thank you for playing! See you next time!" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        }

     }
     while(play=='Y');

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your do while loop

```
do
{
    cout << "Choose an operation." << endl;
    cout << "Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply: " << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cin >> operation;
    cout << "" << endl;

    if (operation > 3 || operation < 1)
    {
        cout << "Your operation choice isn't valid!  Please try again, using 1, 2, or 3."
             << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "Choose an operation." << endl;
        cout << "Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply: " << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cin >> operation;
        cout << "" << endl;
    }
}
while (operation > 3 || operation < 1);
```

should be

```
do
{
    cout << "Choose an operation." << endl;
    cout << "Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply: " << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cin >> operation;
    cout << "" << endl;

    if (operation > 3 || operation < 1)
    {
        cout << "Your operation choice isn't valid!  Please try again, using 1, 2, or 3."
             << endl;
    }
}
while (operation > 3 || operation < 1);
```

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42 ! This was super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the do-while loop if you want to give only one reattempt to the user to select the correct operation. Keep that block this way

```
cout << "Choose an operation." << endl;
            cout << "Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply: "<<endl;
cout << "" << endl;
            cin >> operation;
            cout << "" << endl;

            if (operation > 3 || operation < 1)
            {
                cout << "Your operation choice isn't valid!  Please try 
again, using 1, 2, or 3." << endl;
                cout << "" << endl;
                cout << "Choose an operation." << endl;
                cout << "Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply: " 
<< endl;
                cout << "" << endl;
                cin >> operation;
                cout << "" << endl;
            }
```

OR
if you want to print the error message only for first wrong attempt and for all succedding wrong attempts you can do in the following way:

```
int flag=0;
do{
cout << "Choose an operation." << endl;
                cout << "Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply: "<<endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
                cin >> operation;
                cout << "" << endl;

                if ((operation > 3 || operation < 1)&&flag==0)
                {
                    flag=1;
               cout << "Your operation choice isn't valid!  Please try again, using 1, 2, or 3." << endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    cout << "Choose an operation." << endl;
                    cout << "Enter 1 to add, 2 to subtract, or 3 to multiply: " 
    << endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    cin >> operation;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                }
} while(operation > 3 || operation < 1);
```